# GA4 (Google Analytics 4) - Is there a way to obtain a list of urls that are both an entrance and exit?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

Without using engagement rate, I'm looking for a way to determine pages/urls that are both an entrance and exit in the same session (bounces/single-page views in a session) using Google Analytics 4 (GA4). Has anyone found a solution in the Reporting (or using Data Studio or Big Query) that can achieve this?

I'm also curious whether this is data that is only accessible when utilizing Big Query.